# "userdb validation failed: email: Path `email` is required."

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Hello then i try to create new user i get error "message": "userdb validation failed: email: Path `email` is required."

cannot find there is a bad code field

controller.js

```
const { response } = require('express');
let Userdb = require('../model/model');

// create and save new user object

exports.create = (req, res) => {
  // validate requast
  if (!req.body) {
    res.status(400).send({ message: 'Laukas negali būti tusčias!' });
    return;
  }

  // new user
  const user = new Userdb({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    gender: req.body.gender,
    status: req.body.status,
  });

  // save user to database
  user
    .save(user)
    .then((data) => {
      //res.send(data)
      res.redirect('/add-user');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: err.message || 'Kuriant kūrimo operaciją įvyko klaida',
      });
    });
};

// retrieve and ruturn all users

exports.find = (req, res) => {
  Userdb.find();

  if (req.query.id) {
    const id = req.query.id;

    Userdb.findById(id)
      .then((data) => {
        if (!data) {
          res.status(404).send({ message: 'Nerastas naudotojas su id' + id });
        } else {
          res.send(data);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error gaunant naudojo id' + id });
      });
  } else {
    Userdb.find()
      .then((user) => {
        res.send(user);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        res
          .status(500)
          .send({
            message:
              err.message || 'Gaunant naudotojo informaciją įvyko klaida',
          });
      });
  }
};

// update a new user by id

exports.update = (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body) {
    return res
      .status(400)
      .send({ message: 'Atnaujinant duomenis laukai negali būti tušti!' });
  }

  const id = req.params.id;
  Userdb.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body, { useFindAndModify: false })
    .then((data) => {
      if (!data) {
        res
          .status(404)
          .send({
            message: `Negalima atnaujinti naudotojo su ${id}.Naudotojas nerastas!`,
          });
      } else {
        res.send(data);
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error atnaujinti nepavyko' });
    });
};

// Delete a user with user id

exports.delete = (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;

  Userdb.findByIdAndDelete(id)
    .then((data) => {
      if (!data) {
        res
          .status(404)
          .send({ message: `Negalima ištrinti su id ${id}. Blogas id` });
      } else {
        res.send({
          message: 'Naudotojas ištrintas!',
        });
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: 'Negalima ištrinti naudotojo su id=' + id,
      });
    });
};
```

model.js;

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  gender: String,
  status: String,
});

const Userdb = mongoose.model('userdb', schema);

module.exports = Userdb;
```

router.js;

```
const express = require('express');
const route = express.Router();

const services = require('../services/render');
const controller = require('../controller/controller');

/**
 * @description Root Route
 * @method GET/
 */

route.get('/', services.homeRoutes);

/**
 * @description add users
 * @method GET/ add-user
 */

route.get('/add-user', services.add_user);

/**
 * @description for update user
 * @method GET/ update-user
 */

route.get('/update-user', services.update_user);

// API

route.post('/api/users', controller.create);
route.get('/api/users', controller.find);
route.put('/api/users/:id', controller.update);
route.delete('/api/users/:id', controller.delete);

module.exports = route;
```

render.js;

```
const axios = require('axios');

exports.homeRoutes = (req, res) => {
  // Make a get request to api users
  axios
    .get('http://localhost:3000/api/users')
    .then(function (response) {
      res.render('index', { users: response.data });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.send(err);
    });
};

exports.add_user = (req, res) => {
  res.render('add_user');
};

exports.update_user = (req, res) => {
  res.render('update_user');
};
```

connection.js;

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    //mongoDB connection string
    const con = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });

    console.log(`MongoDB connected: ${con.connection.host}`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

server.js;

```
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');

const connectDB = require('./server/database/connection');

const app = express();

dotenv.config({ path: 'config.env' });
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

//log requests
app.use(morgan('tiny'));

// mongoDB connection

connectDB();

// parse request to body-parses
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//set view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
//app.set("views",path.resolve(__dirname,"views/ejs"))

//load assets
app.use('/css', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/css')));
app.use('/img', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/img')));
app.use('/js', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/js')));
//css/style.css

//load routes

app.use('/', require('./server/routes/router'));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: add this midlleware 

`app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: there i need to put this code ?

Comment: upper of `app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}))`

Comment: thanks its work , but now when i press save at mongodb i saw that data is created but at page nothing is dislpayed u know why ?

Comment: after save do you get data again ?

Comment: yes its work but i dont see on main page a dislpay with name email status its worked and data get it but front end doesnt creating a display with user

Comment: could you log what the server returns when creating user?

Comment: },
    {
      _id: '61813675e040d195fa82d851',   
      name: 'Jonas555 Petrutis555',      
      email: 'sdsdsd555@gmail.com',      
      status: 'Atsijunges',
      __v: 0
    },
    {
      _id: '61813773086e328978655e52',   
      name: 'jurgis pertrus',
      email: 'zalgis@gmail.com',
      status: 'Atsijunges',
      __v: 0
    }
  ]
}
GET / 304 - - 74.628 ms
GET /css/style.css 304 - - 0.606 ms
GET /js/index.js 304 - - 0.662 ms

Comment: you did get data at frontend ?

Comment: MongoDB connected: cluster0-shard-00-01.2rz1d.mongodb.net
GET /api/users 200 957 - 64.235 ms
GET / 304 - - 119.171 ms
GET /css/style.css 304 - - 3.551 ms
GET /js/index.js 200 86 - 5.857 ms
GET /add-user 304 - - 7.732 ms
GET /css/style.css 304 - - 2.205 ms
GET /js/index.js 304 - - 4.501 ms
POST /api/users 302 62 - 80.182 ms
GET /add-user 304 - - 6.329 ms
GET /css/style.css 304 - - 0.717 ms
GET /js/index.js 304 - - 0.729 ms

Comment: so let me know you get data from backend but frontend couldn't display data ?

Comment: yes frontennd didint dislpay it

Comment: i fix it but now i just see numbers didint see a name gmail just apear table with 1,2,3,4 :D

Comment: i find a mistake thats for your time !

Comment: I add my answer if it possible accept that

Answer (score 0):

add this middleware `app.use(bodyParser.json());`
upper of `app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}))`
to get data from front